# Search for sponsored ad campaigns that businesses are running on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-search

How do you search for sponsored ad campaigns that businesses are running on Facebook?

I would like to search other companies' sponsored campaigns.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please take the [tour] and checkout [ask].